# Ajax File-upload progress without any plugin Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

How to get progress of File upload in JQuery such that I can update status bar about file upload.

Below is my file upload code using Ajax in JQuery:

```
         $('button').click(function(e) {
             var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
               $.ajax({
                  url: 'FileUploadExample',
                  type: 'post',
                  data: formData,
                  async: true,
                  cache: true,
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false,
                  success: function(returndata) {
                  }
             });

       });
```

While googling this issue I cam across jquery.form.min.js plugin which have option `uploadProgress`.

How can I get progress of upload without using any plugin in JQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: check my answer bro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using JQuery xhr element, like this

```
var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlerFunction, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

and in progressHandlerFunction you can access e.loaded and e.total of progress like

```
progressHandlerFunction(e)
{
    console.log(e.total+""+e.loaded);
}
```

$.ajaxSettings.xhr(); is the real XMLHttpRequest element, and in native JS you can bind a handler on XMLHttpRequest.upload onProgress event, then you can get the event.total and event.loaded, The progress event will trigger every time event.loaded changes value.

- event.total = Total size of HTTP request.
- event.loaded= Currently uploaded value.

You can do anything with this 2, you can get the percentage by doing 
`var percent=Math.round((event.loaded/event.total) * 100);`  and adjust your loading bar width accordingly.